# I discovered a way to hide an element using the data-html2canvas-ignore=”true”. However, while this hides the element it still leaves an empty space

Tags: javascript, html, html2canvas

```js
var testbutton = document.getElementById("testbutton");
var content = document.getElementById("content");
testbutton.onclick = function () {
   html2canvas(content, {
     "onrendered": function(canvas) {
       document.body.appendChild(canvas);
     }
   });
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.4.1/html2canvas.min.js"></script>

<p>
  <a id="testbutton" href="javascript:void(0);">test</a>
</p>

<div id="content">
    <div class="element-1">1. Is visible</div>
    <div class="element-2" data-html2canvas-ignore="true">2. No visible</div>
    <div class="element-3">3. Is visible</div>
</div>
```

Is there a way to actually remove that element so that the resulting rendered image doesn’t leave that empty space?

Comment: Did you find any solution to this one?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using any Framework? If yes, your framework might have some html functionality or attribute to do this.

For example in Angular you would manage it with`*ngIf` .

It will help you to delete the empty element from your `DOM`

Comment: The Html need to show this div but in image not shown. This is my requirement.

Comment: I don't quite understand can you maybe send a code snippet so that I can help ?

Comment: already I attached snippent check it. in this example No visible is not shown bt space is there

Comment: I am using javascript only not angular project.